# Django link table row to view

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, row

new to coding. I'm creating an inventory table'with the django framework. I'd like to be able to click on a table row (which is a part) that will then parse that row/part information to a detail view. from what I understand table rows are inline elements and inline elements are psuedo code which current HTML does not allow for an anchor tag to be thrown in (bad practice?) so I need to use some javascript. Currently, the inventory view shows when I use runserver (http://127.0.0.1:8000/inventory/) but clicking on any row does nothing. Here is what I have so far;

inventory.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}

<br>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Part Number</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Supplier</th>
        <th>S.O.H</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    {% for part in parts %}
    <!-- need to make these table rows link to their respective parts
    class="table_row" href="{{ selected_part.partnumber }}/detail">{{ selected_part.partnumber }}-->

    <tr data-href="{% url 'detail' part.pk %}">
        <td>{{ part.pk }}</td>
        <td>{{ part.partnumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ part.description }}</td>
        <td>{{ part.location }}</td>
        <td>{{ part.supplier }}</td>
        <td>{{ part.stockonhand }}</td>
    </tr>

    {% endfor %}

    </tbody>

</table>

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('inventory/', inventory_list, name='inventory'),  # URL path for inventory_list view
    path('<str:pk>/', part_information, name='detail'),
    path('', index, name='index'),
]
```

custom.js

```
$('tr[data-href]').on("click", function() {
    document.location = $(this).data('href');
});
```

base.html has `<script src="/docs/4.4/dist/js/custom.js"></script>` before the `</body>` tag.

I think the issues is in my javascript file. I'm pretty new to this and simplified explanations would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below in your custom.js file. When the page is loaded then this function $(document).ready() gets executed initialising the tr on what to do 'On Click'

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('table tr').click(function(){
        window.location = $(this).data('href');
        return false;
      });
    });
```